# File download using Guzzle and Dropbox API on laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, dropbox-api, guzzle

I'm trying to create a function that I can use to download a specified file to a local folder on my machine. The request is successful and I do receive the filedata, however, I can't figure out how to extract the and write it to the specified path. How can I do it ?

Here's my function :

```
public function dropboxFileTransfer()
{
   $local = fopen('files/get.zip', 'r');

    $file = $this->client->get('https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/auto/dropbox-sdk-php-1.1.5.zip', [
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . \Session::get('dtoken'),
        ],
    ]);

    $stream = Stream::factory($file->getBody()->__toString());

    $dest = Stream::factory($local);

    $dest->write($stream);

    return 'ok';
}
```

Comment: If `$local` is the destination file than you probably at least want to open it in "write" mode

Comment: @CodyCaughlan my bad ! changing the mode to 'r+' totally did the trick, I'm such a newbie. Anyway I saw that the file is saved inside the zip file, ( get.zip contains dropbox-sdk-php-1.1.5.zip ), that's not the behavior I want, but changing to fopen('files/', 'r+') gives me an error saying : " fopen(files/): failed to open stream: Is a directory ". How can I do it ?